# postgresql doesnt bind to ip of docker composition

Tags: ip, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a postgresql9.5 container using docker-compose (docker 17.06, compose 1.16 compose-file v2):

```
   postgis:
    build:
       context: ./postgis
    environment:
       ALLOW_IP_RANGE: "0.0.0.0/0"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "nc", "-zv", "localhost", "5432"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5
    container_name: postgis
    networks:
         vpcbr:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.10.3
```

I am using a bridged network to build the composition

The postgresql setup can be found here

https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis

There is a start.sh script and set-postgis.sh, those modifie pg_hba.conf to use 0.0.0.0 (accept everything)

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0              md5
```

my postgresql.conf is listening to all IPs:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I have tried to set the listen_address to 10.10.10.3  and even 0.0.0.0 (?) but nothing seems to work and the postgresql doesnt bing to the ip of the composition, postgresql **only works on localhost**

Is there something that I am overlooking ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker exec into the container and check what postgres is binding to:

```
netstat -plunt
ss -plunt
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Comment: I have rerun the composition on and other computer and it runs without problems (docker v17 and docker-compose version 1.14.0). I can see port 5432 open and accepting connections into the postgis: 4cad8050453c:postgresql geoserver.inspire:60392 ESTABLISHED

Comment: I have postgis with: listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
port = 5432